# Conflicting DATA - Duplicated values

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro that fills the missing Data with specific Data from another sheet , the codes works perfectly in copying pasting data from excel of the client and prepare the data needed to start the work but the only problem here below

Code:

```
   With Worksheets("Feuil2") 
   ' reference "target" sheet (change "Target" to our actual target sheet name)
     With .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'reference 
         its column B range from row 1 down to last not empty one
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then 
 ' if any blank cell in referenced range. this check to avoid error thrown by subsequent 
    statament
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=index(GDC!" & rng.Offset(, 1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",match(RC[-1],GDC!" & rng.Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",0))" 'fill blank cells with a lookup (well, sort of) formula
            .Value = .Value 'get rid of formulas and leave values only
            Cells.Select
        End If
    End With
End With
```

This code works perfectly in matching and filling data but when for e.g find a duplicated value it copy only the first value not the second one

See the image below to better understand the main problem :

[image]

As you can see in the image The problem that in column A i may have data repeated twice like this value P20845 which in column F it is repeated  one with the name of Ghaith and the other with the name of sirine but as you can see in the column A it is just with the name also of Ghaith and there is no name of sirine
Anyidea or better solution in solving this and getting all the needed DATA? .

Best Regards

POLOS

Comment: I've read through this question several times and I still cannot tell *what* your exact issue is. Can you please try to explain once more?

Comment: @dwirony thank you for your answer , In the Image there is one value `P20845 column A with the name of Gaith in front of it  ` what I want  is when  I'm running my code and found duplicated values it take both the result in front of the first data and the second one like this `column B the value P20845 is repeated twice one with name of ghaith and one with the name of sirine  ` so is there any way to get in column A `in front of P20845 something like this Ghiath/sirine ` **see image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a dictionary

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddValues()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet, masterDict As Object, arr() As Variant, i As Long, rng As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Set wsTarget = wb.Worksheets("Feuil2")
    Set masterDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With wsSource
        arr = Intersect(.Columns("A:B"), .UsedRange)
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not masterDict.exists(arr(i, 1)) Then masterDict.Add arr(i, 1), GetAllMatches(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), wsSource)
        Next i
    End With

    With wsTarget
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange)
            On Error Resume Next
            rng.Offset(, 1) = masterDict(rng.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next rng       
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Function GetAllMatches(ByVal findString As String, ByVal dupString As String, ByVal searchRng As Worksheet) As String

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim concatenatedString As String
    concatenatedString = vbNullString

    With Intersect(searchRng.Columns(1), searchRng.UsedRange)

        Set foundCell = .Find(findString)
        If foundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then concatenatedString = foundCell.Offset(, 1)

        Dim currMatch As Long
        currMatch = 0

        For currMatch = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, findString)

            Set foundCell = .Find(What:=findString, After:=foundCell, _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not foundCell Is Nothing And InStr(1, dupString, concatenatedString) = 0 Then
                concatenatedString = concatenatedString & "/" & foundCell.Offset(, 1)
            Else
                concatenatedString = foundCell.Offset(, 1)
            End If
        Next currMatch
    End With
    GetAllMatches = concatenatedString
End Function
```

**Output in Feuil2**

[image: Output]

Comment: thank you for your answer I'm testing your code but I'm facing an issue in running it ,  it keeps looping without stop ... can I share my file with you some how ? tank you so much

Comment: So sheet2 in my code would be your left image.  You could replace Intersect(.Columns("F"), .UsedRange) with .Range("F1:F7")   and Sheet1 is your left image and you can replace  Intersect(.Columns("A"), .UsedRange)  with .Range("A1:A6."). I have edited in where you would put these replacements. Let me know.

Comment: please last question can I modify this to do `foundCell.Offset(, 2)` in the column C ???

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry, I tried to make another column like this https://imgur.com/Crhavyx `Feuil1` and what I want is to get also those data in `Feuil2` but in another column :) :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168810/discussion-between-qharr-and-polos-tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this instead?

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, myrow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastrow = 1

For i = 1 To 7
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sht1.Range("A:A"), sht2.Range("F" & i).Value) = 0 Then
        If i = 1 Then
            lastrow = 1
        Else
            lastrow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If

        sht1.Range("A" & lastrow).Value = sht2.Range("F" & i).Value
        sht1.Range("B" & lastrow).Value = sht2.Range("G" & i).Value
    Else
        sht1.Range("B" & sht1.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=sht2.Range("F" & i).Value).Row).Value = sht1.Range("B" & sht1.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=sht2.Range("F" & i).Value).Row).Value & "/" & sht2.Range("G" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @diwrony , thank you Is it possible to modify sheets for example the column A in Sheet1 and the column F in Sheet2 ???

Comment: @POLOSTutorials Updated

Comment: I tested your code but something wrong it is copying what is located in sheet1  because previosly  before you update your answer it worked and  what is missing is just changing between sheet `ColumnA` in sheet1 and `ColumnF` in sheet 2 if you want can I share my file with you ?